# Formatting CKEditor Text with Proper Styles and Syntax Highlighting

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor and have also added the Syntax Highlighter plugin (([Code Snippet](http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet))) to my setup. However, I am struggling to output CKEditor text with the correct styles (from CKEditor), including the desired syntax highlighting (from the Code Snipped Plugin).

I have been searching for a solution for over three hours and haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer. Can someone help me, with how to enable proper formatting of the text with respect to CKEditor's styling and syntax highlighting?

Here is an example:

**Input:**

[image: Input:]

**Output:**

[image: Output:]

And here is the corresponding code:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>I&#39;m an instance of <a href="http://ckeditor.com">CKEditor</a>.</p>
<pre>
   <code class="language-javascript">
      var i = "test";
      alert(i);
   </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit funny that you said you've been looking for an answer for 3 hours as it is explained right in the official [documentation for this feature](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_codesnippet). Sometimes it makes sense to just check the docs, probably :)

> #### Target Page
>
> To see the highlighter styles on the target page where CKEditor content is displayed, you will need to load the `highlight.js` script and theme's stylesheet on this page. You can either reuse a copy of `highlight.js` placed in the `ckeditor/plugins/codesnippet/lib/highlight` directory or download your own copy from the [highlight.js download page](http://highlightjs.org/download).
> (...)

Read more details and grab some code here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_codesnippet-section-target-page

Comment: Thank you,sry it seems like I didn't read it ._. I'll try it if I'm home :)

Comment: You're welcome, it really was pretty amusing :) Glad to be able to help and have fun using CKEditor!

Comment: I have another question. I've read, that I have to use Javascript (The Function _hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();_ to highlight the things... Is there any way, to bypass javascript? I can't use it in my situation...